# Toggle class with Twitter Bootstrap glyph icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, toggleclass

I have set a toogle-class with Bootstrap glyph icons, but something went wrong to my CSS file. I do not understand where there is the mistake. The problem is that here in [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CGJmE/14/) the toggle-class works properly the icon arrows make the right movement up and down when i click over. But [here](http://tommywebdesigner.com/Vision%20General.html) in the page i am working, it does not do exactly the same. when i click over, the arrow makes a weird movement too. I have investigated in my files and i am not finding the cause. Which might be my mistake? what i am missing in the page?

Comment: Found out the problem, i have removed the value 200 to: $sib.find('.accordion-toggle1 i').toggleClass('icon-arrow-down icon-arrow-up', 200);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the problem, i have removed the value 200 to: `$sib.find('.accordion-toggle1 i').toggleClass('icon-arrow-down icon-arrow-up', 200);`